# JPA/Hibernate Spring boot-primary key one entity referred as an instance to other entity not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have generated master tables using liquibase. I have created the corresponding models in spring boot now I want to maintain a relation ship between those models.

I have one table called Vehicle_Type, it is already pre-populated using liquibase.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="VEHCILE_TYPE")
public class VehicleType {

    @Id
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="DISPLAY_NAME")
    private String displayName;
    
    @Column(name="TYPE")
    private String type;
    
    @Column(name="CREATED_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    
    @Column(name="UPDATED_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime updateDate;
    
    
    
}
```

now what I want to achieve is, I have one child entity, I have refer the `VehicleType`  instance inside that entity as depicted below

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table(name = "NON_MSIL_VEHICLE_LAYOUT")
public class NonMsilVehicleLayout extends BaseImagesAndLayout {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "NMV_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "NON_MSIL_VEH_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1, name = "NMV_SEQ")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "VEH_TYPE", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private VehicleType vehicleType;

    public interface VehType {
        String getVehType();
    }

}
```

The problem is when I tries to save entity `NonMsilVehicleLayout`, then **it tries to first insert the data in VEHICLE_TYPE table also.** which should not going to be happen.

I don't want that, I want JPA will pick the correct ID from VEHICLE_TYPE table and place it inside the corresponding table for `NonMsilVehicleLayout`, because the `id` of `VEHICLE_TYPE`  table is act as foreign key in `Non_Msil_Vehicle_Layout` table.

```
log.info("Inside saveLayout::Start preparing entity to persist");
        String resourceUri = null;
        NonMsilVehicleLayout vehicleLayout = new NonMsilVehicleLayout();
        VehicleType vehicleType=new VehicleType();
        vehicleType.setType(modelCode);
        vehicleLayout.setVehicleType(modelCode);
        vehicleLayout.setFileName(FilenameUtils.removeExtension(FilenameUtils.getName(object.key())));

        vehicleLayout.setS3BucketKey(object.key());
```

I know I missed something, but unable to figure it out.

Comment: How did you create and assign `vehicleType`?

Comment: see my edits for that, I have created the instance of VehicleType and then assign the relevant value, and then set the instance to the MsilVehicleLayout

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `VehicleType` instance setting only the `type` field and set the `vehicleType` field of `NonMsilVehicleLayout` to that new instance. Since you specified `CascadeType.ALL` on `NonMsilVehicleLayout#vehicleType`, this means to Hibernate, that it has to persist the given `VehicleType`, because the instance has no primary key set.

I guess what you rather want is this code:

```
vehicleLayout.setVehicleType(
    entitManager.createQuery("from VehicleType vt where vt.type = :type", VehicleType.class)
        .setParameter("type", typeCode)
        .getSingleResult()
);
```

This will load the `VehicleType` object by `type` and set that object on `NonMsilVehicleLayout#vehicleType`, which will then cause the foreign key column to be properly set to the primary key value.

Comment: Thank you so much Christian for the solution, however I have solved the same, please see my own answer post.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after some workaround, I got the mistake, the column name attribute was incorrect, so I made it correct and remove the `referencedColumn` and Cascading.

Incorrect:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "VEH_TYPE", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private VehicleType vehicleType;
```

Correct:

```
 @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "VEHICLE_TYPE")
    private VehicleType vehicleTypes;
```

also I have added the annotation `@Column` in the referende entity `VehicleImage`

```
public class VehicleType {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID") // added this one
    private int id;
 }
```

That bit workaround solved my problem, now I have achieved what I exactly looking for.